# matlab model -- access base workspace variables

Tags: matlab

I am running my test.m file to create variables in my base work space. This is the content of my `test.m` file :--

```
a=10;       % define a variable with particular value
b=20;       % define a variable with particular value
c=0;        % define a variable with particular value
```

In my MATLAB model now i am trying to access the variables a & b. But it is returning me the value `zero` for both a & b.

I am using a function call generator to trigger a model every 10 msec.

```
Solver type : Fixed Step
Solver : Discreate(No Continous states)
```

Why i am not able to access the workspace variables in my simulink model.

Please see the attached print shot.

[image: Matlab model base Workspace]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an Inport and you named it with the variable name but it does not affect the variable to it, it is only a port. Try using the Constant block and set it to your variable name ("a" for example)

Comment: thanks its working .... by default variables are created with type double... can i define the type of variable in .m file ... let say int or unsigned char ??

Comment: You are right, by default double is used but you can define your variable type like this : a = int32(10); You can check the Matlab documentation for more data type like int32, int64, uint64 ...

Comment: its working ... here are the detail data types http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numeric-types.html